# Assigning columns in parallel to a data.table

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table, parallel-foreach

I'd like to assign many (up to 2000+) columns to a `data.table`; the process struck me as being eminently parallelizable, but it seems the process isn't handled well by distributing the same `data.table` to many workers.

I expected the following to work:

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

NN = 100
JJ = 100

cl = makeCluster(2)
DT = data.table(seq_len(NN))
alloc.col(DT, 1.5*JJ)

clusterExport(cl, c("DT", "NN", "JJ"))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))

parLapply(cl, seq_len(JJ), function(jj) {
  set(DT, , paste0("V", jj), rnorm(NN))
})

stopCluster(cl)
```

However, this produces an obscure error:

> Error in `checkForRemoteErrors(val)` : 
>     2 nodes produced errors; first error: Internal error, please report (including result of `sessionInfo()`) to datatable-help: oldtncol (0) < oldncol (1) but tl of class is marked.

I guess this is due to how assignment by reference works. Assignment happens on each thread but this doesn't get communicated back to `DT` in the global environment.

Is there no way to add columns to a `data.table` in parallel?

Comment: Well, there's `DT[, paste0("v", seq_len(JJ)) := parLapply(cl, seq_len(JJ), function(jj) rnorm(NN)) ]`, though this is no faster than `DT2[, paste0("v", seq_len(JJ)) := replicate(JJ, rnorm(NN), simplify = FALSE) ]` with 1e5 and 2e3 for your vars.

Comment: Good idea for a working solution, and getting around the assignment-on-workers issue. I wonder why it's no faster...

Answer (score 1):

The following does work on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). (note: mcapply doesn't work on windows) 
I am interested to understand if this is quicker

```
> DT <- do.call("cbind",
               mclapply(seq_len(JJ), function(jj) {
  set(DT, , paste0("V", jj), rnorm(NN))
}, mc.cores = detectCores()))
```

### Performance

running on 12 cores

> NN = 100000
>   JJ = 100
>
> user  system elapsed
>     1.172   2.756  41.707
>
> NN = 100
>     JJ = 2000
>
> user  system elapsed
>     4.060  11.152  24.101
>
> NN = 1000
>     JJ   = 2000
>
> user  system elapsed
>     6.580  15.712 139.967

### Suggestion

I use something like this to get 2M columns and 600 rows
(still  not optimal), hope it fits your requirement

```
system.time(
  DT2 <- as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(NN*JJ), ncol = JJ))
)
```